# Starting a Python script on a raspberry via plink (not responding crontab)

Tags: python, cron, plink

I have written a `script.py`, which opens a tk window and draws with turtle in the canvas the window contains. I want to start this script via a plink using:

```
plink.exe -pw raspberry pi@pi-fisch00 python /home/pi/script.py
```

But I always receive an error:

```
script.py line 32, in <module> root = Tk() 
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I think the same error is causing that the crontab is not executing the `script.py`.

My entry in the crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/pi/script.py
```

The syntax should be right, because other scripts are working and if I put `python /home/pi/script.py` in the cmd manually everything is fine. The `script.py` gets executed. How can I fix this and let the crontab execute the `script.py`? Why can't I execute the `script.py` via plink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message you are getting:

> no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

You are attempting to run something that requires an X11 display, which isn't going to be available from within cron's context (and likely not via plink either, unless you are running an X11 display server locally *and* have enabled X11 forwarding).

Typically, if you have something that needs access to the display you need to run it from within an existing desktop session.  There are ways to work around this; for some thoughts on that topic see:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display

Comment: thanks a lot! the solution is:

`*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 python /home/pi/script.py`

I have no idea why I did not find it....